# Laravel Composer autoload Uncaught TypeError

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, composer-php, homestead

I pulled a clean **laravel** from laravel/laravel. I'm getting this error when I type `composer update`. I'm running on vagrant homestead, php 7.0.2. This is a clean project.

I have not modified the .env **file** or composer.json.

Composer update works on other projects I had already.
This happens only for new ones.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKUbD.png

Comment: did you try running `composer dump-autoload` before composer update?

Comment: It gets the same result

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json`? It looks like there's something with your configuration.

Comment: Not sure why this has +2 votes. This exact question was asked yesterday, and closed as too broad. Your issue is local to your environment. You likely have global composer issues.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Any way to fix it? Or "just make a new vm " way ?